# Перестал работать pip

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-2.x

Как под убунтой заствить пип работать если поменял системый питон с 2.7 на 2.6 Валиться с такой ошибкой.

```
pip install Mako
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip

python --version
Python 2.6.9
```

Я руками изменил симлинки

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     /usr/bin/python2 -> /usr/bin/python2.6
```

При этом после смены питона удалил и заинсталил пип через apt-get

UPD. я вернул системный питон 2.7

```
python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
```

Но когда я вытаюсь создать виртуалаьное окружение у меня появляется такая ошибка.

```
    virtualenv --python /usr/bin/python2.6  /home/skif/pythonenv3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.6
New python executable in /home/skif/pythonenv3/bin/python2.6
Not overwriting existing python script /home/skif/pythonenv3/bin/python (you must use /home/skif/pythonenv3/bin/python2.6)
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/skif/pythonenv3/bin/python2.6 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/compat/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ordereddict
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2375, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 724, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 922, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 817, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/skif/pythonenv3/bin/python2.6 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Comment: там разные версии у него. добавте `python --version` в вопрос.

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, нахрена вы поменяли системный питон???

Comment: нужно протестить работу моего приложения на питоне 2.6 , я уже прочитал, что лучше использовать вирт енв, но он тоже не стартует с питоном 2.6, с 2.7 все огонь

Comment: Нужно было просто поставить дополнительную версию питона, а не удалять системную. Питоны 2.6 и 2.7 отлично устанавливаются одновременно

Comment: я не удалял, просто симлинки подправил

Comment: Тогда верните симлинки на место :) А для использования питона 2.6 создайте вот этот вот вирт енв командой `virtualenv --python /usr/bin/python2.6 env` (где `env` это любое название каталога на ваш вкус)

Comment: я вернул системный питон 
python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1

Comment: Выглядит так, будто у вас каталог /home/skif/pythonenv3 был не пустой и из-за этого всё сломалось

Comment: создал все тоже самое в /home/skif/pythonenv3 те же ошибки.